# How do I configure Ant to run (not just compile) Scala?

Tags: scala, ant

Is there an Ant taskdef somewhere that provides a `<scala>` task that will use my SCALA_HOME and which supports `classname=`, `<classpath>`, `<arg>`, `<jvmarg>`, etc., analogous to `<java>`?

[Scala ant tasks](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/98) only defines `<scalac>`, `<fsc>`, and `<scaladoc>` Ant tasks (and [configure ant for scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665635/configure-ant-for-scala) discusses those tasks). However, there is no `<scala>` task for running Scala applications, which seems to be an oversight. I know I can [cobble together a `<java>` task to run Scala](http://scriptlandia.blogspot.com/2007/04/how-to-compile-and-run-scala-program.html), but that seems rather inconvenient and round-about.

Comment: I assume you have good reasons for choosing Ant, but if you're not familiar with [SBT](https://github.com/harrah/xsbt/wiki) you might want to give it a shot. The Scala community seems to be converging on SBT -- for example, the compiler build is switching to it.

Comment: yup, I'm using Ant because I'm not building my Scala app, I'm running it as part of a larger automation pipelin. I use my Scala app to do some work, Ant's FTP task top upload to a web server, etc; i.e. several things which are very easy to do in Ant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be an ant task for running scala yet.  I think there are two reasons for that:

Firstly, the one you allude to in your question - you can cobble together a  task to do it.  In fact, the "scala" executable is just a batch/sh script to run java with the right classpath and options.

Second, I think most scala projects use sbt, and the majority of the remainder use maven, so I guess nobody has run across the need for a specialized ant task for execution yet.