# Scala ant build not working

Tags: scala, ant

```
<target name="init">
      <property
        name="scala-library.jar"
        value="${scala.home}/lib/scala-library.jar"
         />
      <path id="build.classpath">
        <pathelement location="${scala-library.jar}"   />
        <!--<pathelement location="${your.path}"   />-->
        <pathelement location="${build.dir}"   />
      </path>
      <taskdef resource="${scala.home}/tools/ant/antlib.xml">
        <classpath>
          <pathelement location="${scala.home}/lib/scala-compiler.jar"/>
          <pathelement location="${scala.home}/lib/scala-reflect.jar"/>
          <pathelement location="${scala-library.jar}"/>
        </classpath>
      </taskdef>
    </target>

    <target name="build" depends="init">
        <mkdir dir="${build.dir}"   />
        <scalac srcdir="/home/vf-root/workspaces/partnerspace/ipp-partner"
                destdir="${build.dir}"
                classpathref="build.classpath">
          <include name="compile/**/*.scala"   />
          <exclude name="forget/**/*.scala"   />
        </scalac>
    </target>
```

and Following is the output:

init:
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource scala/tools/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

build:

BUILD FAILED
/home/vf-root/workspaces/partnerspace/ipp-partner/build.xml:89: Problem: failed to create task or type scalac
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any / declarations have taken place.

Total time: 0 seconds

Please help of with some soln so that I can get rid of that issue. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [configure ant for scala](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665635/configure-ant-for-scala)

Comment: Please run out, take a newspaper and check the year you are in. You might be time-travelling to the past. Please don't change any source code. Trump might win the U.S. presidency... oh... wait...